# sudo gem install rmagick fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick

I am getting this error when I try to install RMagick on my machine so I can play with Scruffy graph creator:

```
sudo gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: What operating system?  What version of your OS?  What distribution?  What...?

Comment: Sorry for not adding more details. Mac OS X 10.7.2. Build 11C74. Is that the information you need? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you installed ImageMagick using a binary distro or something else which didn't include the headers.  From your `/Users` directory you're probably using OSX.  Assuming so, install ImageMagick using either [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Hi Smathy. At one point I did mess around with Macports but I really did not/do not know what I am doing. What are the steps required to install Macports and ImageMagick? Thanks!

Comment: Best bet is to check out the [RMagick install docs](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#osx) for more information.  There are also instructions for installing with homebrew, just google it.